# Android: ID ressource not recognized

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I do have the following button which is supposed to get an ID:

```
ConstraintLayout cst = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.idMain);
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setId(R.id.buttonId);
    
//set view id, else getId() returns -1ss
cst.addView(btn, 0);
set.clone(cst);//Error
set.connect(btn.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, cst.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 60);
set.applyTo(cst);
```

from ids.xml || res> values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="buttonId" type="id" />
</resources>
```

**Issue**: it doesn't recognize the ID and gives out the Error:
[image: Error]

```
View.generateViewId() //isn't supported
```

**UP**

Comment: Where are you using ConstraintSet/ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Needed ConstraintSet/ConstraintLayout in order to append the Elements to the corrensponding XML-File.